# Conditional within a loop in R: doesn't recognize loop object (i) and throws error: there is no object called 'i'

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a script which installs packages from a character vector as follows:

```
packages <- c("data.table", "dplyr", "tidyr")
for (i in seq_along(packages)) {
  if (is.na(match(i, rownames(installed.packages()))) == TRUE )  
  { install.packages(i)
    }
  library(i)
}
```

When it reads the line `library(i)` it trhows the error:

> Error in library(i) : there is no package called ‘i’

Anyone can help me to unveil why is not it recognizing the `i` element as part of the loop?

Comment: You want the `character.only` argument in `library`, I think.

Comment: I have tried substituting the line `library(i)` with `library(i, character.only = TRUE)`, but I get the error `Error in library(i, character.only = TRUE)` : 
  there is no package called ‘1’}, it occurs to me every time I apply a function within the function `library()`

Comment: Just use `for (i in packages)` (along with `character.only=TRUE`). No need for `seq_along()`. You want it iterate the names, not the indexes.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, yes, I should have mentioned that as well. Sorry about that.

Comment: This should work:  `packages <- c("data.table", "dplyr", "tidyr")
for (i in packages) {
  if (is.na(match(i, rownames(installed.packages()))) == TRUE )
  { install.packages(i)
  }
  library(i, character.only = T)
}`

Comment: thanks both for help

Comment: I have realized that my code would work only if instead of `install.packages(i)` and `library(i)`, the instructiones were `(install.packages(packages[i])` and `library(packages[i])`, if its useful for someone who read this question